# Why the new text I added rotation seems not the same as the first text color and direction when typing?

Tags: texturing, text-object

[image: text]

Text 001 the color values are the same as the first Text but the colors are not the same and the Text 001 when I'm typing something it's adding the letters up direction instead to the right. The rotation is 0,0,0 like the first text I didn't change anything just did : Add > Text

[image: New text add]

Comment: What I did is manual changed in the transform the new text rotation values to the first text rotation values. Strange because at the first both rotation was 0,0,0 only when I selected the transform and rotation I saw the real rotation values. I also wonder why it's no possible to automatic get the first text rotations values to the new text rotation values. I don't want to duplicate because the first text is with other font but it could be nice to be able to copy the transform position,rotation,scale to the new text. Or to duplicate the text but not the font.

Comment: You can copy transforms: use "align selected to active" from the "object/transform" menu. But what is your question, in fact?

Comment: @lemon The question is why when add a new text and then when typing text it didn't add the letters from left to right and add them to top up ? I thought the default is from left to right but the text was written up direction. I mean if I didn't change anything in the transform rotation why the text is written up and not to the right ?

Comment: This would not be from bottom to top. What is the text orientation when you just add it?